# How to solve putty network error permission denied

Tags: ssh, putty

I have used PuTTy.exe for an SSH client. But putty.exe is not working for a 64 bit Windows OS. It works perfectly 32 bit Win OS.

Questions:

- Am I making some mistakes. If so please can you help?
- Is there any app which works on both 32 and 64 machine for win os?
- Is there any cmd commands to connect ssh?

Info:

- Putty.exe ver 0.63.10125.0.
- Run as administrator used no use.
- firewall disabled no use.
- putty.exe runs on a separate drive no use.

Error:

> Network error: Permission denied

Comment: A colleague had this problem and it was fixed by upgrading to Putty 0.70

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh I found the solution for this problem.
Its due to anti virus (ex: norton).
Anti virus blocks all the network permissions.
So I have disabled all smart firewall and browser protection from anti virus.
it worked fine.
Please disable all third party firewalls too then it will work. It is not 32 and 64 bit issue I think so.

Answer (score 4):

It's usually a firewall problem, especially with third party firewalls, in my case TinyWall for Windows. Simply allow the program access.

Answer (score 2):

I have McAfee Endpoint Security and I had the same problem. Whenever I try to connect with putty I get "permission denied". In this case, I opened McAfee Endpoint Security, went to "Firewall". In "Firewall" I went to "RULES" and pressed "Add Rule", wrote the rule name and went to the bottom to "Executables". In "Executables" I pressed "Add", then "Browse", and added PUTTY executable. That solved this problem for me.

Comment: Yes it is advisable to add rule in firewall rules, instead of disabling firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone comes across the same problem:

At some point I started to receive the following errors when trying to run port forwarding

```
Event Log: Local port 2001 SOCKS dynamic forwarding failed: Network error: Permission denied
```

After struggling with that for a while, installed Bitwise SSH where the error would appear as:

```
Failed to enable SOCKS/HTTP proxy forwarding on 127.0.0.1:2001: Address is already in use; bind() in ListeningSocket::StartListening() failed: Windows error 10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

So it was clear that the port is in use - although that didn't show up in CurrPorts. So I resolved that by changing the port number

Comment: +1! I use DoffenSSHTunnel to setup tunnels. Got also "Permission denied" for no reason. After changing a port, I was able to connect successfully.