# Unable to Connect to Office365 for JavaEmailer

Tags: office365, jakarta-mail

I'm on a VPN, but I don't believe that's the issue here. I set my firewall to allow outgoing connections, and my McAfee to ignore both Eclipse and Java.

I know this looks like a duplicate. I promise it's not. I have tried literally EVERYTHING I have found on Stack Overflow the past 3 days, and this thing still gives me:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 
smtp.live.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at edu.montana.fs.MailAttachment.<init>(MailAttachment.java:67)
    at edu.montana.fs.MainCall.main(MainCall.java:90)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
    ... 4 more
```

This is my mailer code (with emails and pwd stripped out):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MailAttachment {
    public MailAttachment(String filepath, int errorCount, int recordCount)    {

        final String SMTP_HOST = "smtp.live.com";
        final String SMTP_PORT = "587";
        final String SMTP_USER = "user@outlook.com";
        final String SMTP_PWD = "password";

        final String from = "server@institute.edu";
        final String to = "user@institute.edu";

        final String subject = "Test";
        final String messageContent = "Testing Message";

        final Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("mail.smtp.user", SMTP_USER);
        config.put("mail.smtp.pwd", SMTP_PWD);
        config.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", SMTP_HOST);
        config.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
        config.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        config.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(SMTP_USER, SMTP_PWD);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(config, auth);

        try {
            final Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(messageContent);
            message.setSentDate(new Date());
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(SMTP_HOST, 587, SMTP_USER, SMTP_PWD);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Mail successfully sent: " + to);
            transport.close();
            //Transport.send(message);
        } catch (final MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Is there something obvious that I am not doing right? I have been through at least 5 complete revamps of this class, and I am open to suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you connect to that from something else, e.g. Putty? `putty -raw -P 587 smtp.live.com` That works for me here. If not you might to talk to your network admins.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Rup! Hopefully I didn't do this wrong. I opened up command prompt in Windows, changed to my PuTTY directory, typed the command, a new window popped up for my PuTTY with an error message saying "Network error: Permission denied". (Same thing when I tried to go to it again through PuTTY frontend.) Unfortunately, I can't take down the firewall or temporarily disable my antivirus and I'm not sure what to ask my network admins for to get through. Can you give me a suggestion?

Comment: I guess just explain to them what you're trying to do - i.e. connect to smtp.live.com port 587 - and ask them to help you make it work. The 'permission error' [does sound like it's McAfee](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21571446/243245) though, but if you've already configured that to ignore Eclipse and Java and it didn't help then maybe there's something else that needs configuring, and your network admins would be in the best position to know what.

Comment: Thank you again, Rup! I'll go bug them now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just so everyone else knows, the issue was the network firewall/security. Apparently being connected through a VPN did not give a Java program enough privileges to run an emailer, even when I have network admin level access tied to my Active Directory account (which is what my VPN access works off of). I was able to test this on a server with a physical location on the business premises, and a wired connection to the network.